# Convert array of objects with same property to one object with array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
let data = [
  {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
  {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith'}
]

console.log(data)
```

I want to transform this into one object like this

```
obj = {firstName: ['John', 'Mike'], lastName: ['Doe', 'Smith']}
```

should I use reduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic solution with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```
let result = data.reduce((obj, o) => {
  // get all keys of object
  Object.keys(o)
    // iterate over the keys
    .forEach(k => {
      // define property if not defined
      obj[k] = obj[k] || [];
      // push the value to the array
      obj[k].push(o[k]);
    })
  // return object
  return obj;
  // set initial value as an object for result
}, {})
```

```js
let data = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Mike',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  }
]

let result = data.reduce((obj, o) => {
  Object.keys(o)
    .forEach(k => {
      obj[k] = obj[k] || [];
      obj[k].push(o[k]);
    })
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a new version of the object.

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

With reduce, we first pass in a function that executes on each item and returns a new output value, then we pass a second parameter defining the initial structure of the single output value.

```js
let data = [
  {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
  {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith'}
]

// o = the current output value
// i = the current item in the array
let result = data.reduce((o, i) => {
  // Add the first/last names to the corresponding array
  o.firstName.push(i.firstName)
  o.lastName.push(i.lastName)
  // Return the new current output value
  return o
}, { firstName: [], lastName: [] }) // Sets the initial output value

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [
  {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
  {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith'}
]

var firstName = [];var lastName = [];
data.forEach(function(item){
    firstName.push(item.firstName);
    lastName.push(item.lastName);
})

let obj = {};
obj.firstName = firstName;
obj.lastName = lastName;

let dataModified = [];
dataModified.push(obj);

console.log(dataModified);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a single iteration, functional, non-mutating solution:

```js
let data = [
  {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
  {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith'}
]

let result = data.reduce((res, {firstName, lastName}) => ({
  firstName: [firstName, ...res.firstName],
  lastName:  [lastName,  ...res.lastName]
}), {firstName: [], lastName: []})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the logic more generic, irrespective of the properties known

```js
let data = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Mike',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  }
]

let result = data.reduce((o, i) => {
  for (const key in i) {
    if (!o[key]) {
      o[key] = [];
    }
    o[key].push(i[key]);
  }
  return o
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple thing we can do is to call [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) two times, once on the first names, and once on the last names.

```js
let data = [
  {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
  {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith'}
]

let result = { 
  firstName: data.map(i => i.firstName), 
  lastName: data.map(i => i.lastName) 
}

console.log(result)
```